# i tried hard but not getting out of this IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python-3.x

Indentation error
i am just trying my level best to solve but can u help me to solve this

```
for i in range(len(m)):
        if m[i]<m[i+1]:
            m[i]+=1
        else:
            m[i+1]
```

Answer (score 1):

In python usually we use a tab (4 spaces) to indent:

```py
for i in range(0,len(m)-1):
    if m[i]<m[i+1]:
        m[i]+=1
    else:
        m[i+1] # this wont do anything
```

Here you go.

Notice that I had to subtract 1 from your range function because other wise it would get an IndexError.